# Mocking File returns NPE

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

Trying to mock the code but getting NPE. I am using Powermockito v2. I am still learning Mockito, please correct me if you find any incorrect ways of testing.

Here is the test class:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(CellConfig.class)
public class CellConfigTest {
    @Test
    public void testCellsMap() throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> cellMap = new HashMap<>();
        cellMap.put("key1", "value1");

        CellConfig cellConfigSpy = PowerMockito.spy(new CellConfig());
        PowerMockito.when(cellConfigSpy, PowerMockito.method(cellConfig.class, "cellMap"))
                .withArguments(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.anyList()).thenReturn(cellMap);
        Paths paths = PowerMockito.mock(Paths.class);
        Path path = PowerMockito.mock(Path.class);

        Stream<String> mockStream = PowerMockito.mock(Stream.class);
        Files filesMock = PowerMockito.mock(Files.class);
        PowerMockito.when(filesMock.lines(path)).thenReturn(mockStream); // NPE

        cellConfigSpy.publicMethod();

    }
}
```

Here is the method under test:

```java
public Map getCells() {
    //does few things
    Map m = getCellsInfo(dir, cellList);

}

private Map getCellsInfo(String dir, List cList) {
    File[] files = new File(dir).listFiles();
    if (null == files) {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
    return cellMap(dir, cList)
}

private Map<String, String> cellMap(String cellDir, List<String> cellKeys) {
    Map<String, String> cellMap = new HashMap<>();
    if (null != cellKeys) {
        cellKeys.forEach(key -> {
            try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(cellDir + key))) {
                stream.forEach(value -> cellMap.put(key, value));
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        });
    }
    return cellMap;
}
```

What would be a suggested way to mock this code?

Comment: You should show the stack, it may be filesMock which is null, or path (and you're not showing how path is built)

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException at java.nio.file.Files.provider(Files.java:97)`. Looks like the issue is with path. How do I mock it? Line:97 -> `return path.getFileSystem().provider();`

Comment: Let's start with the obvious problem here, which is that you shouldn't test `private` methods directly. Private methods should be tested using a `public` entry point (i.e some public method). This will automatically mean that you won't need to perform `PowerMock` wizardry to treat this like a public method. Can you please share the code where this method is called?

Comment: Question updated. I am calling `cellConfigSpy.publicMethod();`

Comment: 1. your code replaces the key for each value... 2. why mock? why not provide a test directory (structure)??

Comment: @xerx593 Data need to be picked from two different directories. The reason to mock is to increase CC. Jacoco shows the try/catch as not covered.

Comment: it doesn't explain 1. and is no excuse for 2.! ;) ?

Comment: Let's say, the cell info would be available in two directories and the API is expected to return ALL the cell info as a map.

Comment: @akortex91 Any advice on how better to achieve this?

Comment: Your test should start by invoking the `getCells` and then going down to the private ones through the invocation chain.

Comment: @akortex91 Understood. I have made the changes. But `Files.lines(Paths.get(cellDir + key)))` is throwing NPE. Could you share how to avoid NPE in this case?

Comment: My personal opinion is I don't like to use Mockito (and especially powermockito) to test my code. Instead, I often use interfaces for which I have a production and a test implementation. In your case for example, you may have an interface which returns what Files.lines() does. Then in your production implementation you use Files.lines(), while in your test implementation you use whatever you wish to mock the behaviour. It's my personal opinion, I have been using Mockito for years but after I tried this approach, I have not been able to come back